# MessageEmbed is not a constructor

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm getting an error "MessageEmbed is not a constructor" it works with only sending a message, but not with an embed. What could be this issue?

```js
const MessageEmbed = require('discord.js');
const { Manager } = require('erela.js');
const nodes = require('./Nodes');

module.exports = (client) => {
    client.manager = new Manager({
        nodes,

        send(id, payload) {
            const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(id);
            if (guild) guild.shard.send(payload);
        }
    })
        .on('nodeConnect', node => console.log(`Node ${node.options.identifier} connected.`))
        .on('nodeError', (node, error) => console.log(`Node ${node.options.identifier} had an error: ${error.message}.`))
        .on('trackStart', (player, track) => {
            client.channels.cache
                .get(player.textChannel)
                .send(new MessageEmbed().setDescription(`Now playing: \`${track.title}\``).setColor('ORANGE'));
        })
        .on('queueEnd', (player) => {
            client.channels.cache
                .get(player.textChannel)
                .send(new MessageEmbed().setDescription('The queue has ended. Leaving the channel.').setColor('ORANGE'));

            player.destroy();
        });
};
```

Comment: `const MessageEmbed = ` should be `const { MessageEmbed } = `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const MessageEmbed = require("discord.js")
```

is incorrect. The correct way is:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
```

Note the `{}`. The curly braces are a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). When you import or require discord.js, it is importing an object with everything in discordjs. By using destructuring assignment, you are only picking out the parts you require.